# Laravel-excel cannot update records "WithUpserts" - not found

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to update database but i got this error:

> Interface 'App\Imports\WithUpserts' not found
> I can't understand where is mistake.
> Everything from examples. My import class here:

```
namespace App\Imports;
use App\bmwprice;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;    

class bmwimport implements ToModel, WithUpserts
{
   public function model(array $row)
   {
       return new bmwprice([

           'NUMBER' => $row[0],
           'NUMBER2' => $row[1],
           'WEIGHT' => $row[2],
           'VPE' =>     $row[3],
           'VIN' =>     $row[4],
           'NL' =>      $row[5],
           'TITLE' =>   $row[6],
           'TEILEART'=> $row[7],
       ]);
   }
   public function uniqueBy()
   {
       return 'NUMBER';
   }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithUpserts; // below other imports using use
```